# How to run jmeter script in chrome

Tags: jmeter

I have alrady created jmeter script and I need to run this in chrome browser. Original script  recording done with the IE. Is this possible?

Any other way to change the running browser of alrady created script?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter doesn't kick off a real browser so it absolutely doesn't matter with what you recorded your test.

If you would like JMeter to pretend being Chrome - just add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to your Test Plan and configure it to send [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header with the value of desired [Chrome browser version User-Agent string](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/)

[image: JMeter Chrome User Agent]